# Image MacOS to IMG file to use for restoring on other Macs

Tags: osx, macos, image

I have custom MACOS on iMac, MacBook and Mac Mini, its our company background, added software and removed some default software.

I am looking to find a way to image one of the OS volume to img or dmg file and restore it to volumes of other macs.

My challenge is our fleet of mac are not the same machine. we have iMac, deferent generation with deferent storage space size and so is with our MacBook and Mac Mini, so best for me is to have an image of the prepared Mac Machine and be able to restore/deploy it to other machines regardless of their storage size. I have looked in to mac deploy software and OS deployment options and they are not simple or straight forward. we deploy images on daily bases, we need it to be least interactive. that's why best way for us is to have the image ready and just restore it to machines, at this moment we have scripts that are using MDS to read image from NAS and then run script afterwards , this means we have to come back to the machine and run the script afterwards , update the machine and pack it. so in wrap up, a software or command line to create an image of the OS not the entire drive or volume to be able to restore it to volumes on other machines regardless or what it is or what the storage/ HDD size is. I also understand that M1 chips may be deferent so I can have 2 image. Best, Mehdi

Comment: "removed some default software" - that's going to prevent any OS newer than Mojave from booting. If you mess with the boot image it will flip to Recovery & not let you past until you re-install a known-good OS. I'd recommend using Apple's own DEP & Configurator structures, perhaps with TwoCanoes or Jamf & leave the base OS alone.

Comment: Thank you for your honest answer, both jamf and MDS are quite hands on , i was looking for a more less step approach , but unfortunately there is none at the moment possible, i think i have to stick with installing os and running the script to do the rest.